# Why does Words with Friends say I can make more points?

Tags: words-with-friends

Check out this screenshot:
[image]

This isn't the first time "Word Strength" implies that I can make way more points on my move than I think I can, but it's the first time it's happening on the first move with such a big gap.

How could I be making the 40+ points? Even if I used all my letters, and hit a DW spot, I would only get 18 points. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this information online :

35 bonus points are awarded whenever a player uses all 7 tiles on their rack in a single turn.

That would match with the advice that the game gives you.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [board editor](https://www.wordswithfriendscheat.io/board-editor) you could have played BOATIES, BONIEST, BOOTIES, and a few other words for 53 points from the center tile.